# After complete installation IPFS not working on Browser

Tags: node.js, ipfs

i have installed IPFS on server and server on browser its not working

```
root@vultr:~/live_horce_chain# cd go-ipfs
root@vultr:~/live_horce_chain/go-ipfs# ipfs daemon
Initializing daemon...
Adjusting current ulimit to 2048...
Successfully raised file descriptor limit to 2048.
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip4/202.182.100.59/tcp/4001
Swarm listening on /ip6/::1/tcp/4001
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready
```

when i enter url 202.182.100.59:5001 or localhost:5001 or 127.0.0.1:5001 or 127.0.0.8080 or 202.182.100.59:8080 but not working. what was going wrong??

it should show IPFS panel

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are looking for is `202.182.100.59:5001/webui` or `localhost:5001/webui`.